# Laravel Job Batching table relationship with User model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-queue, job-batching

I am using Laravel [Job Batching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#job-batching) feature and I have dashboard where I display the progress of Batch(Processed, Failed, Pending jobs … etc.).

Each user has it's own dashboard and I want to display the progress of Batch based on logged in user, but I can't see any relationship with User model with batch table `job_batches`.

Is it possible to somehow make relationship with those tables? or any alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That is possible, but there is a lot of hoops to go through. This could also be a question about, a general approach to extending functionality of `Laravel`.

Some quick assumption is that you use some sort of Authentication when creating the batches, so you can do `Auth::user()->id`.

Create your `user_id` for the `job_batches` table with a migration.

```
    Schema::table('job_batches', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->after('name')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

`Laravel` uses a [BatchRepository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Bus/DatabaseBatchRepository.php) to create the Batches in the `job_batches` table, extend this and add our logic to insert Users into the row. I have added the custom repository, to App\Repositories namespace. In general use the current logic and update the user_id after the core `Laravel` logic has been executed.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repostories;

use Illuminate\Bus\DatabaseBatchRepository;
use Illuminate\Bus\PendingBatch;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class BatchRepository extends DatabaseBatchRepository
{
    public function store(PendingBatch $batch)
    {
        $batch = parent::store($batch); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        $this->connection->table($this->table)
            ->where('id', $batch->id)->update([
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            ]);

        return $batch;
    }
}
```

For `Laravel` to use your new class, you need to extend the current class in the `Container`. Third parameter is the table name, assuming you are using the default table. This is done in a provider. Either put it in existing provider, or create a new one, remembers to register it.

```
use Illuminate\Bus\BatchFactory;
use Illuminate\Bus\BatchRepository;
use Illuminate\Database\Connection;
use App\Repostories\BatchRepository as CustomBatchRepository;

...

public function register()
{
    $this->app->extend(BatchRepository::class, function () {
        return new CustomBatchRepository(resolve(BatchFactory::class), resolve(Connection::class), 'job_batches');
    });
}
```

Tested with the following snippet, this will add user_id to the table rows.

```
Bus::batch([new TestJob(), new TestJob()])->dispatch();
```

**The relationship**

BatchRepositories returns a [Batch](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Bus/Batch.php) that is not an Eloquent Model. So i would suggest creating your own Eloquent model for relationship purposes and make logic to convert it into the `Batch` when you want to have the batch functionality at hand eg. `finished()`.

Firstly Eloquent Model for your `Batch.php`. Meanwhile also preparing the `toBatch()` functionality, to convert Eloquent model to [Batch](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Bus/Batch.php) class.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Bus\BatchRepository;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Batch extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'job_batches';

    public function toBatch()
    {
        return resolve(BatchRepository::class)->toBatch($this);
    }
}
```

Create your relationship method on your `User.php`.

```
public function batches()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Batch::class);
}
```

I tested the relationship setup with the following snippet, which worked.

```
User::first()->batches->first()->toBatch();
```

Secondly imagine having multiple batches, you would be able to get the [Batch](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Bus/Batch.php) classes with higher order functions easily. Or else use them as a proper relationship.

```
User::first()->batches->map->toBatch();
```

**Note**

Be careful to import correct `Batch` and `BatchRepository` classes. I added imports to secure you include the correct ones, also the following snippet to the provider, makes you able to instantiate my custom batch repository.

```
use App\Repostories\BatchRepository as CustomBatchRepository;

$this->app->bind(CustomBatchRepository::class, function () {
    return new CustomBatchRepository(resolve(BatchFactory::class), resolve(Connection::class), 'job_batches');
});
```

At your own risk, you can see [my solution](https://github.com/mrhn/bus-user-id), in a rough testing ground created for this question. There is a controller and relationship on the user. Not certain if there is leftovers for other StackoverFlow projects.

Answer (score 1):

Only I modify this for when is a job executed locally:

```
$this->connection->table($this->table)
        ->where('id', $batch->id)->update([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id ?? null,
        ]);
```